# R - Find shortest distance between points across two dataframes

Tags: r, distance, latitude-longitude

I need to identify the shortest distance between points, across two dataframes.

Dataframe `biz` contains individual businesses, including their coordinates:

```
biz <- structure(list(name = c("bizA", "bizB", "bizC", "bizD"), 
lon = c(-3.276435,-4.175388,-4.181740,-3.821941), 
lat = c(11.96748,12.19885,13.04638,11.84277)),
class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

biz
  name       lon      lat
1 bizA -3.276435 11.96748
2 bizB -4.175388 12.19885
3 bizC -4.181740 13.04638
4 bizD -3.821941 11.84277
```

Dataframe `city` contains market cities, including their geocoordinates:

```
city <- structure(list(name = c("cityA", "cityB", "cityC", "cityD"), 
lon = c(-4.7588042,-3.2432781,-3.0626284,-2.3566861), 
lat = c(10.64002,10.95790,13.06950,13.20363)),
class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

city
   name       lon      lat
1 cityA -4.758804 10.64002
2 cityB -3.243278 10.95790
3 cityC -3.062628 13.06950
4 cityD -2.356686 13.20363
```

For each business in `biz`, I need to identify which market city is closest, and list the name of that market city in a new column:

```
biz
  name       lon      lat     city
1 bizA -3.276435 11.96748
2 bizB -4.175388 12.19885
3 bizC -4.181740 13.04638
4 bizD -3.821941 11.84277
```

I know that I can use packages like `geosphere` to measure the distance between `bizA` and `cityA` coordinates. I'm struggling with: how to compare `bizA` to each city, minimize the distance, and then list that closest city in dataframe `biz`.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Just loop over the entries in `biz`, and calculate the distance from that entry to every entry in city.  Use `which.min()` to choose the smallest and put it into the city column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `st_nearest_feature` from `sf`:

```
cbind(
  biz,
  nearest_city = city[
    st_nearest_feature(
      st_as_sf(biz, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326), 
      st_as_sf(city, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
    ),
  ]$name
)

although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_nearest_feature assumes that they are planar
  name       lon      lat nearest_city
1 bizA -3.276435 11.96748     cityB
2 bizB -4.175388 12.19885     cityC
3 bizC -4.181740 13.04638     cityC
4 bizD -3.821941 11.84277     cityB
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are multiple ways to do this.
Here is one, that starts by creating all combinations of rows from the two data frames using the `dfcombos` function from [here](https://github.com/sashahafner/jumbled).
(I think there are some alternatives in packages on CRAN.)

Here the distance is just a random number, to demonstrate.

The closest cities are selected using `duplicated` after sorting with `order`.
There are alternatives to this approach as well, but it seemed simple.

```
source('dfcombos.R')

biz <- structure(list(name = c("bizA", "bizB", "bizC", "bizD"), 
lon = c(-3.276435,-4.175388,-4.181740,-3.821941), 
lat = c(11.96748,12.19885,13.04638,11.84277)),
class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

city <- structure(list(name = c("cityA", "cityB", "cityC", "cityD"), 
lon = c(-4.7588042,-3.2432781,-3.0626284,-2.3566861), 
lat = c(10.64002,10.95790,13.06950,13.20363)),
class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

comb <- dfcombos(biz, city)

comb$dist <- runif(nrow(comb))

comb <- comb[order(comb$dist), ]

closest <- comb[!duplicated(comb$name), ]
```